# Change onclick attribute based on inline css

Tags: jquery, onclick, tagging

This is hard to explain with a lot of background so I apologize for the crazy long question.  Also, I'm still learning so any constructive feedback that can help me be a better developer is appreciated!

I use a jQuery image slider that has a mask to hide all the images, and then a click function makes the images move X # of pixels to the left or right to display the next image within the mask. The number of pixels is defined in an inline style applied to the ul element with jQuery, and changes with each click.  The slider requires that a css value equals the total width of all images, and then the slider calculates how far to slide based on that.

In my case, it's 980px wide. So if you click right, the ul gets "style: left: -980px" added to it. On the next one its "style=-1960px" and so on.

In order to capture how many slides are actually viewed, I would like to write some jQuery that changes the onclick attribute of the Previous and Next buttons based on the value of the style: left that is applied to that ul element.  I wrote some code to do this but it doesn't work quite as expected - it seems like it is changing the onclick attribute based on how many pixels forward the element is sliding rather than the actual value of the css.

What am I doing wrong? My end goal is that when the 1st image is showing, the Prev needs to have a value of Slide 9, and the Next button needs a value of Slide 2.  On the next slide it would change to Slide 1 and Slide 3, and so on.

[Here is a working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/BUa4W/2/)

This is the function I wrote to accompany the slider, but please look at the fiddle as there is a lot more to it. SO requires links to fiddles be accompanied by code:

```
        $j("#next, #prev").click(function() {
          var slideNumber = $j('ul.imgHolder').get(0).style.left;   
          if (slideNumber == '0px'){
                    $j('div#next').attr("onclick", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'Slide 3']);");
                    $j('div#prev').attr("onclick", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'Slide 1']);");
                }
            else if (slideNumber == '-980px'){
                    $j('div#next').attr("onclick", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'Slide 4']);");
                    $j('div#prev').attr("onclick", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'Slide 2']);");
                }
            else if (slideNumber == '-1960px'){
                    $j('div#next').attr("onclick", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'Slide 5']);");
                    $j('div#prev').attr("onclick", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'Slide 3']);");
                }
            else if (slideNumber == '-2940px'){
                    $j('div#next').attr("onclick", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'Slide 6']);");
                    $j('div#prev').attr("onclick", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'Slide 4']);");
                }
            else if (slideNumber == '-3920px'){
                    $j('div#next').attr("onclick", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'Slide 7']);");
                    $j('div#prev').attr("onclick", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'Slide 5']);");
                }
            else if (slideNumber == '-4900px'){
                    $j('div#next').attr("onclick", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'Slide 8']);");
                    $j('div#prev').attr("onclick", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'Slide 6']);");
                }
            else if (slideNumber == '-5880px'){
                    $j('div#next').attr("onclick", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'Slide 9']);");
                    $j('div#prev').attr("onclick", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'Slide 7']);");
                }
            else if (slideNumber == '-6860px'){
                    $j('div#next').attr("onclick", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'Slide 1']);");
                    $j('div#prev').attr("onclick", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'Slide 8']);");
                }
        });
```

Comment: You'll probably get more responses if, instead of posting lots of code, you post a fiddle that demonstrates the problem. I tried reproducing it, but I don't know which slideshow plugin you're using.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, posted a fiddle.

Comment: @surfbird0713 One issue I found is that when going backwards you have a value of `-7840px` that's not being accounted for in your `if else` logic.  Perhaps this is throwing it off as it is keeping the first onclick method that is set.  See the fiddle I'm testing. http://jsfiddle.net/BUa4W/3/

Comment: @defaultNINJA, yes, that is the weird thing. If I start the if/else statement at -980, which seems logical to me because the onclick shouldn't change until it gets to the 2nd slide, it really gets wonky.  See this http://jsfiddle.net/LpHwH/ Not sure why that is happening. I can get the next button to work only if I start at 0.

Comment: Also, the slider itself works fine, it's just the onclick attribute for the prev/next buttons in question.

Comment: @surfbird0713 it's ugly but I made too separate `if else` statements depending on if `next` or `prev` was pressed.  Might be better to make it a function if this is what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/LpHwH/2/

Comment: @defaultNINJA thank you! I see a couple of weird things. So, first, the Slider number should be the same for each left value in each function - so if it's -7840px, it should be Prev=Slide 8 and Next=Slide 1, for both of the functions.  So when I look at your alerts they give me the right info but then if I inspect the HTML it's not correct.  If I start at slide one and hit Prev, the left value is -7840px, but Slide 7 is applied to Prev and Slide 9 is applied to Next, even though that conflicts with the logic you wrote. Hope I am making sense.  I'm stumped on this one and my brain hurts!

Comment: @surfbird0713 I'll take a look at it again a little later.  I would trust the alerts more than the HTML.  Typically HTML manipulated by javascript will not be viewable in view source format since the HTML was created when the browser first displayed the markup.

Comment: @surfbird0713 ok I think I see it!  I'll change it and see if helps.  I think I need to just off set the logic by one in each direction.

Comment: @surfbird0713 Let me know how this one works for you http://jsfiddle.net/LpHwH/4/ Think the problem is that the logic needed to be one step ahead or behind depending on if we're going forward or backwards.  Also keep in mind you might not see the changes in the actual HTML since the page doesn't refresh.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35355/discussion-between-surfbird0713-and-defaultninja)